# Proguard build fails with external libraries added

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I have the following build.gradle file

`
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.anuj.auth"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.chathuralakmal:AndroidImagePopup:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.androidessence:pinchzoomtextview:1.0.1'
}
```

`

I have enabled proguard rules but even if I leave the proguard-rules.pro empty I get the following error.
I'm new to the concept of proguard and find it quite confusing.

Here's the message I receive on building the app with proguard rules enabled.

`

```
Warning: com.ceylonlabs.imageviewpopup.ImagePopup: can't find referenced method 'com.squareup.picasso.Picasso with(android.content.Context)' in program class com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
Warning: com.ceylonlabs.imageviewpopup.ImagePopup: can't find referenced method 'com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target into(android.widget.ImageView)' in program class com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder
Warning: com.jakewharton.picasso.OkHttp3Downloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.picasso.Downloader$ResponseException
Warning: com.jakewharton.picasso.OkHttp3Downloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.picasso.Downloader$ResponseException
Warning: com.jakewharton.picasso.OkHttp3Downloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.picasso.Downloader$Response
Warning: com.jakewharton.picasso.OkHttp3Downloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.picasso.Downloader$Response
Warning: com.jakewharton.picasso.OkHttp3Downloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.picasso.Downloader$Response
Note: com.bumptech.glide.Glide: can't find dynamically referenced class com.bumptech.glide.GeneratedAppGlideModuleImpl
Note: io.grpc.Context: can't find dynamically referenced class io.grpc.override.ContextStorageOverride
Note: io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider: can't find dynamically referenced class io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider
Note: io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver: can't find dynamically referenced class javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext
Note: io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver: can't find dynamically referenced class com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory
Note: io.grpc.okhttp.internal.Platform: can't find dynamically referenced class org.conscrypt.OpenSSLProvider

> Task :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease 
Request to incrementing alive workforce from 0. Current workforce (dead or alive) 4
thread-pool size=8

Note: there were 6 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
Warning: there were 5 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Thread(Tasks limiter_5): destruction

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
24 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 21 up-to-date
```

`

Answer (score 0):

`minifyEnabled true` enables proguard. So you have 2 options:
1. If you don't need proguard then just make it false
2. Otherwise you need to write proguard rules for the libraries causing problem. You can easily get them on Git.